# About universal Ext space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g$. Consider the Ext space over $J_{d_1}\times J_{d_2}$ i.e., the vector space of isomorphism classes of extensions of line bundles of degree $d_2$ by line bundles of degree $d_1$. ($J_i$ denotes the Jacobian of degree $i$).

There is an action of $Hom(L, Q)$ on Ext^1(L,Q), where $(L,Q)\in J_{d_1}\times J_{d_2}$. Is there a vector bundle over $J_{d_1}\times J_{d_2}$ whose fibre over any given $(L,Q)$ is $\frac{Ext^1(L,Q)}{Hom(L, Q)}$? Notice that as $(L,Q)$ varies the $dim~Ext^1(L,Q)-dim~Hom(L, Q)$ remains constant.

For simplicity let us assume that $dim~Ext^1(L,Q)-dim~Hom(L, Q)\geq 0$.

Comment: What is the action of $Hom(L,Q)$ on $Ext^1(L,Q)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a natural action of $\operatorname{Hom}(L,Q)$ on $\operatorname{Ext}^1(L,Q)$, namely the trivial one.

There is a natural  vector bundle stack over $J_{d_1}\times J_{d_2}$ whose fiber at every point $(L,Q)$ is the stack quotient $[\operatorname{Ext}^1(L,Q)/\operatorname{Hom}(L,Q)]$, that is a groupoid such that its $\pi_0$ (i.e., set of isomorphism classes of objects) is $\operatorname{Ext}^1(L,Q)$ and each object has automorphism group canonically isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(L,Q)$.

It can be obtained by applying the (arrow-reversing) equivalence between $D^{[-1,0]}_{\text coh}$ and abelian cone stacks to the perfect complex which is dual to $R\pi_*(L^\vee\otimes Q)$, where $$\pi:X\times J_{d_1}\times J_{d_2}\to J_{d_1}\times J_{d_2}$$ is the natural projection.

Details of the equivalence between derived category and abelian cone stacks, including the fact that it maps perfect complexes with perfect amplitude in [-1,0] to vector bundle stacks and conversely, can be found in [Behrend-Fantechi](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9601010).